# How to delete particular data from core data attribute (column) in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, database

I am doing core data in Swift 3. I am able to store data and able to fetch, working fine. But, while trying to delete particular data suppose string data, its not able to do.

Following is my code

```
        //Delete if existing data there
        let context = DatabaseController.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "UserData")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "userFocusData==\(node.label.text!)")

        let result = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        let resultData = result as! [UserData]

        for object in resultData {
            context.delete(object)
        }

        do {
            try context.save()
            print("saved!")
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            self.showAlert(message: "Data not able to save, please try again later.", title: kText_AppName)
        } catch {

        }
```

And its getting crash at following line

```
        let result = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

And crash report is

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath Sharepoint not found in entity <NSSQLEntity UserData id=6>'
```

But, I am passing some string, that string I want to delete from database.
Can anyone suggest me, how to fix this, I have not used core data well.

Comment: try this fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "UserData.userFocusData =
 %@",node.label.text!)

Comment: In your code, you are trying to delete array of objects from ***resultData*** but only saving the context after all deletions happened. You can try: Add `try context.save()` code inside the for loop, or find what object you want to delete and take for loop out.

Comment: @Sahil, thanks, its helped me.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift 3**
In this Code i am delete data based on id

```
func deleteTrip(Id:String)
    {
        managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"your entity")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", "\(Id)")
        do
        {
            let fetchedResults =  try managedContext!.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject]

            for entity in fetchedResults! {

                managedContext?.delete(entity)
                do
                {
                    try managedContext.save()



                }


                catch let error as Error!
                {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }


            }
        }
        catch _ {
            print("Could not delete")

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue found.

So, the solution answer is

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "UserData.userFocusData = %@",node.label.text!)
```