# Swift 3 - Core Data, delete single object

Tags: swift3

I am wondering on how to delete a single object in core data. I have a vc with a label on, when a user swipes left or right it shows each input from core data.
I want the user to be able to delete the selected input on the label without delete all of the other inputs.

Here is the code that I have tried below

This is where I swipe and left

```
@objc func handleSwipes(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.direction == .left {
        currentArrayIndex = (currentArrayIndex + 1) % coreNames.count
        mainSubNameTF.leftToRightAnimation() // Swipe Animation from left to right for mainSubNameTF

    } else if sender.direction == .right {
        currentArrayIndex = (currentArrayIndex + coreNames.count - 1) % coreNames.count
        mainSubNameTF.rightToLeftAnimation() // Swipe Animation from right to left for mainSubNameTF

    }
    mainSubNameTF.text =  coreNames[currentArrayIndex].subName // Shows subName Core Data to mainSubNameTF
```

}

This is where i Delete the object

```
func deleteSub() {

    do {
        coreNames = try context.fetch(SubNames.fetchRequest())

        for each in coreNames {
            context.delete(each)
        }
        appDelegate.saveContext()
    } catch {

    } 

}
```

Comment: Please Check This Link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47654671/8028808